# Link tidylib library to C application

Tags: c, compilation, linker, include

I am trying to use the `tidylib` library within my C application. When compiling, I get the following errors:

```
$ make
rm -f sbo-export
cc sbo-export.c safarilib.c -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl  -L/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/include -o sbo-export
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_tidyCreate", referenced from:
      _safari_init_session in safarilib-c7ab6a.o
  "_tidyParseString", referenced from:
      _safari_init_session in safarilib-c7ab6a.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [default] Error 1
```

safarilib.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <tidy/tidy.h>
#include <tidy/buffio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include "safarilib.h"

void usage( char *username, char *password )
{
    TidyDoc tdoc = tidyCreate();
    char *input = "<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>";
    tidyParseString( tdoc, input );
}
```

Any suggestions?

---

**Further Infos:**

For installing libtidy, I did the following:

- Downloaded libtidy from `http://tidy.sourceforge.net` and then
- followed the instructions form the file `tidy/build/readme.txt`

My library is installed here:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/bin
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/bin/tab2space
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/bin/tidy
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/include
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/include/buffio.h
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/include/platform.h
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/include/tidy.h
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/include/tidyenum.h
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/lib
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/lib/libtidy-0.99.0.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/lib/libtidy.a
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/lib/libtidy.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/lib/libtidy.la
```

Comment: You don't seem to actually *link* with the library. Add e.g. `-ltidy` somewhere at the end.

Comment: Oh man.. This worked. Can you answer the question with this and state some more information? (Some reference or similar.)

I am a C beginner and this is very important for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From compiler option it's look you have not specified tidylib.

```
cc sbo-export.c safarilib.c -L/usr/local/lib -lcurl  -L/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/libtidy/include -o sbo-export
```

Here you need to add `-ltidy` and probably path by `-L` .

Some additional info about [linking](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/tools-compiling.html).

Comment: THank you very much. I was missing out the following convention: "The rule is that if the library is called libsomething.a, you give cc the argument -lsomething. For example, the math library is libm.a, so you give cc the argument -lm. A common “gotcha” with the math library is that it has to be the last library on the command line."